# How to rewrite a circular radial gradient starting at origo from objectboundingbox to userspaceonuse?

Tags: svg, radial-gradients

Here I have a radial gradient expressed in `objectBoundingBox` coordinates:

```html
    <svg width="800" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
        <radialGradient id="myGradient3" cx="75%" fx="75%" cy="25%" fy="25%" r="50%" fr="0%">
          <stop offset="25%" stop-color="gold" />
          <stop offset="75%" stop-color="red" />
        </radialGradient>
      </defs>
    
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="url('#myGradient3')" />
    </svg>
```

Consider it an example of a radial gradient with the following invariants:

- The radial gradient is circular (not elliptical)
- Only one shape refers to the radial gradient.
- The attributes `cx`, `cy`, `fx`, `fy`, `fr`, `r` are set

What should I recalculate the attributes to if I want to convert it to use `userSpaceOnUseCoordinates`?

Here is my best attempt in pseudo code

```
const shapeBox = shape.getBBox() // {x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200}
userspaceCX = cx * bbox.width // 150 = 75% * 200
userspaceFX = fx * bbox.width // 150 = 75% * 200
userspaceCY = cy * bbox.height // 50 = 25% * 200
userspaceFY = fy * bbox.height // 50 = 25% * 200
userspaceR = r * sqrt(bbox.height^2 + bbox.width^2) // 70.71 = 50% * sqrt(5000) = 50% * sqrt(200^2 + 200^2)
userspaceFR = fr * sqrt(bbox.height^2 + bbox.width^2) // 0 = 0% * sqrt(5000) = 50% * sqrt(200^2 + 200^2)
```

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="200">
      <defs>
        <radialGradient id="myGradient3__1" cx="150" fx="150" cy="50" fy="50" r="70.71" fr="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ffd700"/>
          <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#f00"/>
        </radialGradient>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="url(#myGradient3__1)"/>
    </svg>
```

But as you can see if you run the code snippets, the converted image is a little different from the original image.

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: I think you allready asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816432/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-raidal-gradient-expressed-in-objectboundingbox-coord/62819625#62819625

Comment: Yes, it seems like it. Thank you for helping me solve this problem last time I had it. I didn't realize that I was having the exact same problem again. I have marked this questions as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation for diagonal length should be

```
sqrt(bbox.height^2 + bbox.width^2) / sqrt(2)
```

instead of

```
sqrt(bbox.height^2 + bbox.width^2)
```

Comment: The example only works for bbox.x = bbox.y = 0. It would be beneficial to give a more generalized answer including the offset values.